# If $f_n\to f$ uniformly and $f_n$ are differentiable, is $f$ differentiable?

Tags: uniform-continuity

Suppose $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ and $f_n$ are differentiable. Is it true that f will be differentiable?

My initial guess is no because $f_n= \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt n}.$ Is this right? And more examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Notice that $f_n$ converges to zero uniformly, so that's not a counterexample. The statement is false, though.

Comment: Yeah, it converges to 0. But does it necessarily mean that f won't be differentiable?

Comment: Yes, because $f$ is identically zero...

Comment: One of the worst titles ever?

Answer (score 3):

Your sequence converges uniformly to 0, which is differentiable. Consider $f_n(x)=\sqrt{x^2+1/n}$, which converges uniformly to $|x|$. Here is an outline of how you would prove that:

1. Prove that the largest difference between $f_n(x)$ and $|x|$ occurs when $x=0$.
2. Prove that if $n$ is large enough, that $|f_n(0)-|0||$ can be made arbitrarily small.
3. Explain why this means that the convergence is uniform.
4. Use the definition of the derivative to show that $|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: Could you give me details?

Comment: I just edited my answer with some steps of proof.

Comment: When I took the limit of $f_n$, I got x and not $\abs(x).$ Could you provide more details of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Remember that $\sqrt {x^2} $ only equals $x $ when $x\geq0$.

Comment: I know the limit of the sup($f_n(0)$, 0)=0, which means it's uniformly convergent. But why would I want to look at the point x = 0. I'm kind of confused about (1).

Answer (score 2):

The limit function doesn't even have to be differentiable anywhere. Take any function $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ that is continuous but nowhere differentiable [such functions exist]. By the [Stone-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) you can find a sequence of smooth functions that converge uniformly to $f$ on $[0, 1]$.

For a more specific example, consider a [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function). The corresponding partial sums form a sequence of smooth functions that converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$ to a nowhere differentiable function.